# How to define a macro with correct spacing around it depending on context?

Tags: spacing, white-space

I want to define a simple macro that will be used in math mode formulae. The macro represents a mathematical relation. The way the relation is displayed (boldface etc) is not important. What matters is the spacing around it.

Specifically, if my macro is `\likes`, I want `$a \likes b$` to appear
with a space before the `b`, but I also want `$\likes(a, b)$` not to
appear with a space before the bracket. Is there a way to write a
single macro that will behave as intended in those different
contexts?

The question is not about what's natural for LaTeX but what's legible
for the user of the macro. I would rather avoid having to write
`\likes{}` or having two versions of the macro, one with spaces and one
without.

[image: Rendered example]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    I want to be able to write all of the following:

    \verb+``$a \likes b$''+, yielding ``$a\ \textbf{likes}\ b$''

    \verb+``$\likes(a,b)$''+, yielding ``$\textbf{likes}(a,b)$''

    \verb+``$(a,b) \in \likes$''+, yielding ``$(a,b) \in \textbf{likes}$''

    \vspace{1ex}
    With the definition \verb+\newcommand{\likes}{\textbf{likes}}+ I get:

    \newcommand{\likes}{\textbf{likes}}

    \verb+``$a \likes b$''+ gives ``$a \likes b$'' (BAD, missing space
    before and after)

    \verb+``$\likes(a,b)$''+ gives ``$\likes(a,b)$'' (GOOD)

    \verb+``$(a,b) \in \likes$''+ gives ``$(a,b) \in \likes$'' (GOOD)

    \vspace{1ex}
    With the definition \verb+\newcommand{\likes}{\textbf{ likes }}+ I
    get:

    \renewcommand{\likes}{\textbf{ likes }}

    \verb+``$a \likes b$''+ gives ``$a \likes b$'' (GOOD)

    \verb+``$\likes(a,b)$''+ gives ``$\likes(a,b)$'' (BAD, unwanted spaces)

    \verb+``$(a,b) \in \likes$''+ gives ``$(a,b) \in \likes$'' (BAD, unwanted  
    spaces)

    \end{document}
```

Comment: To my knowledge it's possible to do if-then-else like things in macros. However, it might be easier and more straight forward to just define a handful of simple macros, like `\likesA`, `\likesB` etc. and use them depending on context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define `\likes` as `\mathbin`:

```
\def\likes{\mathbin{\rm likes}}

%% TEST:
$a \likes b$       % prints: a likes b

$\likes(a,b)$      % prints: likes(a,b)

$(a,b) \in \likes$ % prints: (a,b) ∈ likes

\bye
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you, just what I needed! And works in Latex too as `\newcommand{\likes}{\mathbin{\textbf{likes}}}`.